# Missing '/' path while compiling using scons in CPPPATH expansion

Tags: build, compilation, scons

Fatal error[Pe1696]: cannot open source file "Someheaderfile.hpp"
 Although the path for Someheaderfile.hpp is included with

> COMMON_INCLUDES      =    ['#Source/Interfaces/Common']
>   env.Append(CPPPATH = COMMON_INCLUDES)

The compiler while searching for the mentioned header prints the path as follows

> searched: "SourceInterfacesCommon"

which  is basically all the '/' removed.

The call made was 
myEnv.Library(target, src_files)
and this boils down to

> iccarm --silent -o Prod\somepath_obj\Somefile.o -otherflags
>   -ISource\Interfaces\Common Prod\somepath\Somefile.cpp

So although from the CPPPATH the file was included on the command line when carrying compilation it is not able to locate.

Is there anything which i miss that resulted in 
**Source/Interfaces/Common** being changed to **SourceInterfacesCommo**n

Comment: i am running the build through eclipse environment in Windows ... i have sorted out the issue ... seems to be because of the way i was creating the environment variable.  On changing env = Environment(platform = ['cygwin'], ENV = os.environ) to env = Environment(ENV = os.environ) along with few other changes, everything works fine

Comment: You should create an answer and mark it the answer in case someone else runs into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i have sorted out the issue ... seems to be because of the way i was creating the environment variable. On changing env = Environment(platform = ['cygwin'], ENV = os.environ) to env = Environment(ENV = os.environ) along with few other changes, everything works fine.
Also i am not explicitly mentioning what should be the path seperator between folders to be, rather using os.join.path('X','Y','Z').